# ZXing <FNC> Separator for GS1 bar code

Tags: c#, zxing

I am trying to place in `<FNC1>` separators in my ZXing barcode, I am not sure how these are supposed to be formatted in a string value. I have

```
BarcodeWriterPixelData writer = new BarcodeWriterPixelData()
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Width = 554,
        Height = 120
    }
};
var pixelData = writer.Write("<FNC1>42011111<FNC1>92612123456789000000155015");

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        try
        {
            // we assume that the row stride of the bitmap is aligned to 4 byte multiplied by the width of the image   
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Pixels.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }

        // PNG or JPEG or whatever you want
        bitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);
        bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newBarcode.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

This code generates this image[image]

Which is exactly `<FNC1>42011111<FNC1>92612123456789000000155015`how can I interpolate and insert the FNC1 values? I tried using "]C1" which I found in this solution:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/475

But it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unicode character '\u00f1' instead of "<FNC1>" should work.

Comment: Dude.... I swear you are a freaking angel. I have been banging my head for days trying to figure this out, This will be known as the day Michael saved Marco. Thank you friend. Thank you.